# Can you Copy a UPC from Zxing and Paste on a Web App

Tags: android, web-applications, zxing, barcode-scanner

What I'm trying to do is launch the Zxing App when you push a button and open the native app, then take the resulting barcode number and place it in our database. Is it possible to do this with only having to open the app or do I need to actually create a Native App?

Comment: mostly just looking to see if its plausible. I played with a sample code of the native zxing app in Eclipse but I'm completely new to android development that I dont think i  have a full grasp on how to do it yet. This is for a class project, we have our Web App set up that you type in a upc and it goes into an API and gets all our information. What I'm trying to do is automate that by using the native app if possible

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to place the barcode in your own database without writing some code.
You can use the Zxing app from your own application using their `IntentIntegrator`

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity);
integrator.initiateScan();

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
if (scanResult != null) {
    // place your scan result into the database
}
    // no result found
}
```

Please read this on 'scanning via intent'
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Add the source code required to your project:
[Source code](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=ZXing-2.1.zip&can=2&q=)

Comment: This the right approach -- just noting that you only need `android-integration` from the project not all of the code.